# Replace string with JSX tags

Tags: reactjs

I'm working with **ReactJS** and try to **wrap specific words/phrases in JSX tags**. I have a **data.jsx** where I have an array with objects like `message: "{span}Hello{/span} what's up?"`. Now I'd like to replace **{span}{/span}** with the tags. Sadly I can't use `.replace('{span}', <span>)` for this task. Is there any way to do this?

This might be more complicated if I want to use {span}{/span} many times in the same string. But would be great if there's a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)*:

> * Use it with caution: if its content comes from user input, you'll have a severe security breach.

```js
const obj = {
  message: "{strong}Hello{/strong} what's {em}up{/em}?"
};

const content = obj.message
  .replace(/{/g, '<')
  .replace(/}/g, '>');

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement('span', { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: content } }),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign your `span` data as `Component` and then you can use that as tag after like below,

```
let CustomTag = `${span}`;
```

Then use it as `<CustomTag>Your data here..</CustomTag>`.

**Note:** Component name first letter should be capitalised.

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` like was mentioned previously and I'm not agree with Sophie also in some way.

`Parsing JSX at runtime is error-prone and slow, and can easily have security implications – it wouldn't inherently be any safer than dangerouslySetInnerHTML is.` by Sophie Alpert ([here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3386#issuecomment-78605976))

So, I decided to use this package for this task - [regexify-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regexify-string)

> npm install --save regexify-string

```
regexifyString({
        pattern: /\[.*?\]/gim,
        decorator: (match, index) => {
            return (
                <Link
                    to={SOME_ROUTE}
                    onClick={onClick}
                >
                    {match}
                </Link>
            );
        },
        input: 'Some initial string with [link]',
    });
```